# How does the $experimental-support-for-svg: true; in Compass supposed to be working?

Tags: sass, gradient, compass-sass

Heyy,

In my stylesheet, if I specify:

```
$experimental-support-for-svg: true;
```

When doing linear gradients, how should the output differ from it being `false`?

I'm assuming it should result in a data URI SVG image of the gradient like [here](https://gist.github.com/Shpigford/1835299).

Or, is it this mixin `background-with-css2-fallback()` that should do the SVG magic?

I'm using Compass with CodeKit and the Compass version in it is `0.12.2` and Sass is at `3.2.12`.

What am I doing wrong? I of course do `@import compass` in my stylesheet and other Compass mixins are working fine.

Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't successful implementing this feature either. [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8992462/2817112) helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! It's when I use angles in the gradients when the SVG stops working.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/hilja/pen/wgEIa).

Sorry for the disturbance.